# Program won't give correct number- Console application

Tags: vb.net, console, console-application

**Issue**
I tried to make a program in VB as I thought of giving the language a go. But it didn't give a specific result. It doesn't make sense logically for this not to work. So if somebody could give me an explanation  along with the answer it would be great.
**Objective:**
A series of numbers is given but some are in brackets, e.g (01234)567890. What I want to do is to remove these brackets from the numbers but my attempt for some reason does not work.

**My attempt:**

```
Sub Main()
      Dim input, output, ds, sd as string
      Dim s, f as integer
      Console.writeline(" enter number ")
      Input = Console.readline
      s = Instr(input, "(")
      f = InStr(input, ")")
      ds = input.Substring(s, f - 1)
      Sd = input.Substring( f - 1)
     Input = ds + sd
     Console.writline(output)
     Console.Readline()
End sub
```

Output:

> 01234)567890

*Note: ignore any typos as this was uploaded from my phone and I would like to clarify that I mainly code in other languages.*

Comment: You want just to remove the brackets or also the numbers inside?

Comment: Also, Im seeing that I don't know how you get that output, due to in your code you never use output variable and also you have written `writline` instead of `writeline` that wouldn't even compile...

Comment: If you're learning VB, I'd recommend against using the legacy `InStr` function and instead use the string functions in the .NET framework.

Comment: @Brank-Victoria First of all, "P.S ignore any typos as it was uploaded from phone" I think that's clear enough. And the program is to remove only the brackets,not the number inside it.

Comment: Then you just have to replace those characters to blank, just as the answer of Nithin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help u

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input, input1 As String
    Console.WriteLine(" enter number ")
    input = Console.ReadLine
    input1 = input.Replace("(", String.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty)
    Console.WriteLine(input1)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```